# Using the word "whether" in conditional statements

Tags: word-usage, conjunctions, conditional-constructions, logic

- You can not open your webpage if you don't have a web browser.
- You can not open your webpage whether you have a web browser or not.

In my understanding so far, the first sentence represents a condition "I can't open the webpage without a browser."

The second means the webpage can not be opened, no conditions.

Please correct me!

Answer (score 3):

Many natives are firmly convinced that "if" and "whether" are interchangeable, which is not true. Some natives only use "if," which is wrong. Word to the wise: there are lots and lots of native English speakers out there; not all of them are geniuses. Some of them are pretty ... uh ... but I digress.

A wether is a castrated male sheep. The word you have in mind is always spelled with an "h" following the "w."

Consider the following:

> The mezzo will sing **if** she feels up to it.

Or:

> Hopefully the mezzo will sing for us tonight. Go and find out **whether**
>   she feels up to it.

You can't use "whether" instead of "if" in the first example.

You *could* use "if" instead of "whether" in the second one, and many people would, but it doesn't sound quite right to a native ear that is genuinely attuned to the ... uh ... ***polyphony***, for lack of a better word ... of the English language.

Comment: I agree with the answer, but maybe this part "You can't use "whether" instead of "if" in the first example" would be clearer if we added something like "without change in meaning".

Comment: @DamkerngT.: It's rather "without changing English grammar" rather than "without changing the meaning."

Comment: Interesting. I thought *The mezzo will sing whether she feels up to it* or *The mezzo will sing whether we like it* would be fine in English, even though it'd be an odd thing to say.

Comment: @DamkerngT.: "The mezzo will sing whether she feels up to it" does make a bit of comical sense, yes. However, "The mezzo will have some coffee whether she feels up to it" does not.

Comment: @DamkerngT. I'm afraid not. The alternative "or not" can only be left implicit in embedded questions (*I don't know whether the mezzo will feel up to [or not]*); in adjunctive clauses it must be explicit (*The mezzo will sing whether she feels up to it **or not***).

Comment: @Ricky  I think you are too severe in rejecting "Go and find out **if** she feels up to it". This construction is attested in works of the highest literary quality stretching back to *Beowulf*, which is at least a thousand years old.

Comment: @StoneyB: So what. I don't like it.

Comment: "I don't like it" is not quite the same thing as saying that it reflects imperfect attunement to the polyphony of the English language. I could with exactly equivalent validity (*viz*, none at all) say that your aversion to the usage reflects a monophonic insensitivity to polyphony.

Comment: @StoneyB: You could, but it wouldn't be true. "If" instead of "whether" is the kind of usage up with which one must not put. Keats should be allowed, nay, encouraged, to borrow an expression or two from the gutter, and ridiculed as an impossible snob should he flatly refuse to do so, so long as the gutter is eager to imitate Keats; but he should not be forced to pander to the gutter in an epoch in which the gutter is encouraged to deem itself superior to Keats. ... And I don't even like Keats. Why bring him up, then? I don't know. I hear he was a stickler for something or other ... hmm ...

Comment: I suppose I'll have surrender the heights to you and resign myself to the gutter. But since I will be accompanied by Shakespeare, Milton, Dryden, Swift, Pope, Gibbon, Arnold, and Tennyson (to come no nearer the degraded present than the middle of the 19th century), I shall not want for improving literature.

Comment: @StoneyB: Shakespeare's cool. Folks only pretend to have read Milton. Dryden kind of appeals to my sense of humor, even though some of his so-called experiments are pretty annoying. Swift, uh ... Pope had something. To my shame, I've never read anything by Gibbon. I had no idea Schwartzenegger wrote poetry. He's truly versatile. Tennyson is intriguing, though not necessarily improving. There is something about following prepositions, or not following them, when using "if" instead of "whether," or some such. I'm okay with using "as if" instead of "as though," if that's any consolation to you.

Comment: I'm new on English Language Learners... Is it normal for Comments sections to degenerate into bickering between proscriptivists and descriptivists?

Comment: @DavidKnipe: Depends on who's around and who's having tea or sex (i.e. has no choice but to get away from their computer screen for a few moments).

Comment: @DavidKnipe: Oh, and I do resent the "degenerate" part. I'd much prefer "to turn into a battleground of the age-old conflict between noble and chivalrous prescriptivists and hypocritical, needlessly sanctimonious, lowly, distinctly honorless, and generally boring descriptivists."

Answer (score 0):

The construction "whether ... or not" is used to indicate that a certain condition is not relevant to the issue.

```
You can't drive from Canada to Australia whether you have a passport of not.
```

In this case, while you do need a passport to travel from Canada to Australia, the major impediment is the lack of a bridge across the Pacific ocean, and having a passport does not remove that impediment.

So in the original sentence, there is some impediment to opening the page, other than the lack of a web browser.

So essentially the "whether ... or not" construction is saying that the condition is question is irrelevant. Thus it is not really a conditional construct but an absolute one.

Answer (score 0):

"*Z, whether X or Y*" or "*Whether X or Y, Z*" means that Z is the same if X or Y is true.

> Whether the store has "Call of Duty Black Ops" or "Madden 16", I'm buying a PS4 game.

In the above example, Y reuses X's verb, and it's not necessary to repeat it, but X and Y can contain their own verbs.

> Whether she hates me or she loves me, I still have to go to the party.

Typically X will have a verb, if it doesn't, the meaning will be "X is" or "there is":

> Whether rain or snow, the post office delivers mail.
>
> Whether sick or well, she was at work every day.

Plain old *whether X* with no Y has an implied "or not X" on the end of it.  Usually including the "or not [X]" will sound/read as repetitive but can be included for emphasis.

> I don't know whether she'll go = I don't know whether she'll go or she won't go.

So *whether* is not really a conditional, it's saying something is going to happen regardless of two or more possible outcomes.  It's the opposite of a conditional.